# JS file failed to load in CPanel

Tags: javascript

I am a junior web developer i created a website as a example and i published it. i am also new to CPanel hosting so I was wondering if you could help me. I just hosted my new website.

I had been playing with the code on jsbin and other platforms and everything was running fine, but when I hosted it the javascript seems to be unresponsive. Not sure what to do. This is the first website I've put online and first time I encountered this problem.

http://developerbabu.cf  this is the link of my website.

Why js file not working and what should i do now?
Thanks in advance and I hope you can help me!

Comment: you have the following error `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` you need to put jquery before the bootstrap script tag

Comment: Firstly your domain is suspended ,secondly you should check browser console for any errors you are getting

Comment: check it now domain is available

Answer (score 0):

Replace your HTML code with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html style="height: 100%;">

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="10;url=http://suspended-website.com/">
    <title>iFastNet.com Special offer and Discount Coupon</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="description" content="iFastNet.com Special offer and Discount Coupon">
    <meta name="keywords" content="iFastNet.com Special offer and Discount Coupon">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (top.location != self.location) {
            top.location = self.location.href
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: url('images/backgroundblue.png') top left repeat-x;
            height: 100%;

        }

        BODY.enterPage {
            cursor: hand;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function goto() {
            location.href = "https://ifastnet.com/portal/sharedhosting.php"
        }
    </script>
</head>
<center>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        <a href='https://ifastnet.com/portal/transfer-your-hosting-to-ifastnet.html'>How to upgrade or transfer your
            free hosting account to iFastNet or want to transfer your site from another host to iFastnet? Click here to
            find out how.</a>
</center>
</div>

<body style="height: 100%;" class="enterPage" onclick="goto();">

    <table style="height: 80%; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">

                    <a href="https://ifastnet.com/portal/sharedhosting.php"><img alt="WordPress Hosting" src="http://suspended-website.com/a/images/a.png"></a>

                    <div style="text-align: center; color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">
                        <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;"><a><br>

                        </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').hide();
        $('body').fadeIn(2000);
    </script>


    <!-- Start of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sc_project = 6981613;
        var sc_invisible = 1;
        var sc_security = "c20c0410";
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <div class="statcounter"><a title="tumblr hit
tracking tool" href="http://statcounter.com/tumblr/" target="_blank"><img
                    class="statcounter" src="http://c.statcounter.com/6981613/0/c20c0410/1/" alt="tumblr hit tracking tool"></a></div>
    </noscript>
    <!-- End of StatCounter Code for Default Guide -->


</body>

</html>
```